# how can I solve RunTimeError of input and batch size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch

**

### my input (feature) contains 1 column and 12454 rows whereas my target (label) contains 2 columns and 12454 rows and here's my full code:

### **

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as plt

inputs = genfromtxt('C:/Users/HP2015/Desktop/prog/data/elec_data_inputs.csv', delimiter=',')

target = genfromtxt('C:/Users/HP2015/Desktop/prog/data/elec_data_target.csv', delimiter=',')

inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)

target = torch.from_numpy(target)

train_ds = TensorDataset(inputs.float(), target)

batch_size = 100
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = nn.Linear(1, 2)

preds = model(inputs.float())
preds
```

### when I try to implement this code I get this error:

```
 RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16984/1006819693.py in
    ----> 1 preds = model(inputs.float())
    2 preds

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, *kwargs) 1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks 1109 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks): -> 1110 return forward_call(input, **kwargs)
1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used
1112 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py in forward(self, input)
101
102 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 103 return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
104
105 def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x12454 and 1x2)
```

### how can I set batch size and model to meet the requirements?

---

Answer (score 0):

The Query is based upon the error due to the dimension mismatch during matrix multiplication.
Hence try to reshape the input before you put it in the model.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as plt

inputs = genfromtxt('C:/Users/HP2015/Desktop/prog/data/elec_data_inputs.csv', delimiter=',')

target = genfromtxt('C:/Users/HP2015/Desktop/prog/data/elec_data_target.csv', delimiter=',')

inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)
inputs=torch.reshape(inputs,(12454,1))
target = torch.from_numpy(target)
target=torch.reshape(target,(12454,2))

train_ds = TensorDataset(inputs.float(), target)

batch_size = 100
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = nn.Linear(1, 2)

preds = model(inputs.float())
preds
```

So what exactly is happening that, your input tensor should be a single column tensor with the input data, but it is a single row tensor with all the input points hence when you run it over the Linear(), because the dimensions of doesn't match, it throws the error. 
**Hence it can be changed by adding these 2 lines of code where we have reshaped the input and the target**

```
inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)
inputs=torch.reshape(inputs,(12454,1))
target = torch.from_numpy(target)
target=torch.reshape(target,(12454,2))
```